# How to combine two sql queries of temporary tables into one single query?

Tags: teradata

I got an ask to identify how many customers have activated their membership account. I'd like to combine the below two queries of temporary tables into one single query. Based on that one single query, I will do other query to pull data from the temp table. Can anyone help me with it please?

First temporary table:

CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE Activation1 AS (
Select distinct(ID_NO) as ID_NO, max(Date) as LATEST_INACTIVE_DT
from Table_A
where product_id = 'M'
group by 1
) WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX (ID_NO) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

Second temporary table:

CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE Activation2 AS (
Select distinct(ID_NO) as ID_NO, max(Date) as LATEST_DT
from Table_A
where where product_id = 'M'
group by 1
) WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX (ID_NO) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
;

If I create two temp tables, I would need to do Table A left join table B on ID_no as follows:

select
case when a.LATEST_INACTIVE_DT = b.LATEST_DT then 'Not Activated'
else Activated
end as Activation
count(*) as ACTIVATION
from Activation1 a
left join Activation2 b
on a.ID_NO = b.ID_NO
group by 1;

I'd like to have only one temp table (preferably using CTE as I wanna use this query in Power BI to pull data)

Thank you in advance!

I tried this but not sure if it is right.

WITH Activation1 AS
Select distinct(a.ID_NO) as ID_NO, max(Date) as LATEST_INACTIVE_DT,
from Table_A a
LEFT JOIN (Select distinct(ID_NO) as ID_NO, max(Date) as LATEST_DT
from Table_A
where product_id = 'M'
group by 1) b
ON a.ID_no=b.ID_no
where a.product_id= 'M'
GROUP BY 1;

Comment: Just `WITH Activation1 AS (SELECT ...), Activation2 AS (SELECT ...) SELECT ... FROM Activation1 a LEFT JOIN Activation2 b ON ...`